# SSRS - 1 Stored procedure called executed multiple times

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that returns the description of a product sheet from the product reference.
The product sheet contains: the description of the product, dates, the history of the product, ...
The data comes from a stored procedure called with a SINGLE reference.

The report criterion is currently a single reference.
So everything is ok.

I would like to pass a list of references separated by, for example, a comma and run the PS as many times as there are references to query and make as many product sheets as references.

I hope i was clear.

A big thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you already have a report that produces a result for a single reference. If that is true then the easiest way is probably to use your existing report as a subreport.

In brief...

You will need to create a new report, add a dataset that contains a unique list of references that you want to produce reports for (this could be parameterized too if required).

This might be as simple as `SELECT DISTINCT RefID FROM myTable`

Next add a list control to your report and set its dataset property to the dataset you created above.

In the list's 'cell' right-click and insert a subreport. Now right-click the subreport placeholder and set subreport to be the name of you original report. Set the parameter to be the fields from your dataset above (in this exmaple `[RefID]`).

The list will produce one subreport per entry in the dataset. You can set page breaks from the list control if required.

If this does not help, let me know and I'll update the answer with more details.